# using lastModified on specific elements/classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am ***trying*** to use the JavaScript [lastModified](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_lastmodified2) capability; but not on the entire document (as it appears to be designed for).

```
  var x = new Date(document.lastModified);
```

I want to use this to display the date, of the `lastModified` elements **within a specified class.**

For instance; I have a parent div with class "homepage" I would like to detect when the elements within 'homepage' have been `lastModified`, then display the date of. **But not the common header/footer includes; only within specified class '`homepage`'**

- Open to other suggestions as well; the goal is to simply output a
  date once specific elements are changed/updated/modified.

Comment: I think LastModified is the [Last-Modified HTTP response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified), which is a part of the header of a response. So this is only for a document, and would not be able to be used in more specific terms.

Comment: on what specific element are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is this i think...

```js
$('.example-default-value').each(function() {
    var default_value = this.value;
    $(this).focus(function() {
        if(this.value == default_value) {
            this.value = '';
        }
    });
    $(this).blur(function() {
        if(this.value == '') {
            this.value = default_value;
        }
    });
});
function example_append() {
    $('#example').append($('#example-textarea').val());
    $("#asd").html("This page was last modified on: "+document.lastModified);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); margin: 5px 0pt; padding: 5px;">Example div</div>
<form>
    <div><textarea class="example-default-value" id="example-textarea" style="width: 400px; height: 50px;">Type some text in here to be appended</textarea></div>
    <div><input type="button" value="Append" onclick="example_append()" /></div>
</form>

<p id="asd"></p>
```